# Как из строки получить выражение?

Tags: .net, c#

Описываю задачу:
Пользователь вводит в текстовое поле например:
y = x + 1 + x^2;
Программа должна посчитать значение у. Значение x будет константным и вшитым в программу.
Как реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Написать синтаксический анализатор, который преобразует текст введённый пользователем, в некоторую объектную модель. Дальше могут быть варианты.

1. Модель может быть объектной моделью лямбда-выражений. В этом случае Вы можете просто использовать метод Compile класса LambdaExpression для получения исполняемого метода.
2. Модель может быть в Вашем формате, но после получения разобранного дерева она конверитруется в Expression, и задача сводится к случаю 1.
3. Вы реализуете в Вашей модели паттерн "посетитель" и пишете посетителя, который каждый узел Вашего дерева выражения конвертирует в делегат. После обхода дерева у Вас получается делегат, выполняющий его содержимое.

Comment: Буду пробовать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Через обратную польскую запись это делается.

Comment: В смысле распарсить строку в ОПЗ, а потом уже будет проще сложить/вычесть/умножить/делить?

Comment: Да потом элементарный парсинг идет) и вычисление

Answer (score 1):

vbvm, msscript под винь.

Answer (score 0):

[peg-sharp](http://code.google.com/p/peg-sharp/):

> Эта библиотека создает парсер C# для языка, заданного в грамматиках, разбирающих выражения, а также с дополнительными семантическими действиями.